# Recursive Fetch Request

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to write a recursive fetch function. I am calling an endpoint that accepts a name param and returns their `role` and an array of `direct-subordinates` like so:

```
{
    role: "CEO",
    direct-subordinates: [ "john smith", "bob jones" ]
}
```

I then want to call the function again to request the same data for each subordinate.

Here is the code I have:

```
export const fetchEmployee = async (name) => {
  let url = `https://url.com/to/employees/endpoint/${name}`
  let req = await fetch(url)
  let json = await req.json()
  return json
}

export const recursiveFetchEmployees = async (initialName) => {
  let json = await fetchEmployee(initialName)
  const role = json[0]
  const subordinates = json[1]
  if (subordinates) {
    return {
      name: initialName,
      role: role,
      subordinates: subordinates['direct-subordinates'].map(async (subordinate) => {
        let result = await recursiveFetchEmployees(subordinate)
        return result
      }),
    }
  } else {
    return {
      name: initialName,
      role: role,
    }
  }
}
```

This almost works when called with `recursiveFetchEmployees(employeeName).then((resp) => console.log(resp))`  but the result is:

```
name: "robert robertson",
role: "CEO",
subordinates: (2) [Promise, Promise],
```

How do I change this so the function works its way down the employee hierarchy recursively producing a result like this:

```
{
    name: "robert robertson",
    role: "CEO",
    subordinates: [
        {
            name: "john smith",
            role: "Marketing Manager",
            subordinates: [{
                name: "mary doyle",
                role: "employee",
            }]
        },
        {
            name: "bob jones",
            role: "Development Manager",
            subordinates: [{
                name: "barry chuckle",
                role: "Development Lead",
                subordinates: [{
                    name: "billy bob",
                    role: "Developer",
                }]
            }]
        },
    ],
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Thanks to the fine answer given by @trincot the problem I had was resolved but it introduced another problem. I need to check for and filter out duplicates in the returned results. I introduced a `uniqueNameArray` that gets initialised with an empty array and on every call, it adds the name of the current `initialName` param if it does not already exist in the array. Here is my code:

```
export const recursiveFetchEmployees = async (initialName, uniqueNameArray = []) => {
  if (!uniqueNameArray.includes(initialName)) {
    uniqueNameArray.push(initialName)
    let json = await fetchEmployee(initialName)
    const role = json[0]
    const subordinates = json[1]
    if (subordinates) {
      return {
        name: initialName,
        role: role,
        subordinates: await Promise.all(
          subordinates['direct-subordinates'].map(
            (subordinate) => subordinate && recursiveFetchEmployees(subordinate, uniqueNameArray)
          )
        ),
      }
    } else {
      return {
        name: initialName,
        role: role,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when there is a duplicate it still gets called in the map function resulting in a `subordinates` array that looks like this:

```
    {
       name: "bob jones",
       role: "Development Manager",
       subordinates: [
           {
               name: "barry chuckle",
               role: "Development Lead",
                   subordinates: [{
                      name: "billy bob",
                      role: "Developer",
                   }]
           },
           {
               name: "james jameson",
               role: "Development Lead",
                   subordinates: [{
                      name: "joey joe joe junior",
                      role: "Developer",
                   }]
            },
            undefined,   // <-- This is where there was a duplicate
         ]
     },
```

Is there a way to omit it from the promise list? What ive done above should do that as far as I can tell so Im not sure why it still returns an undefined response.

As always, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Dont know too much js, even less outside of angular, maybe try `return await...` in your  `subordinates` check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no surprise that `.map(async ...` returns an array of promise objects, as an `async` function always returns a promise.

You could use `Promise.all` here:

```
subordinates: await Promise.all(
    subordinates['direct-subordinates'].map(recursiveFetchEmployees)
),
```

Note also that you can just pass `recursiveFetchEmployees` as callback argument to `.map`. There is no need to create that wrapper function.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually astounded that works. How does ```recursiveFetchEmployees``` work without at least being given a param? I assume the map function just passes what its itterating over into the function passed in? Brilliant, thanks for your help!

Comment: `recursiveFetchEmployees` is a function reference that `.map` uses for its repeated calls. It is the `.map` implementation that passes the argument. It really is no different from using an inline function expression. It's just that the signature of `recursiveFetchEmployees` is already fit for a `.map` callback, so no need to have an inline function expression there.