# recursively fetch paginatedData from an API using a continuation token

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, fetch-api

The [Sonatype REST API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/components-api) paginates data in its response with a `continuation token` placed inside the response body; if the continuation token is `null`, you know you're on the last page of results.

I would like to recursively fetch all records from the endpoint with `fetch` (unless there is a better strategy?), updating the url using a query parameter on each recursive iteration and calling the recursive `fetch` on it, and building a storage structure containing the complete list of records in the function. I have been unsuccessful.

To get the first page of records, this works:

```
const requestUrl = `https://{baseURL}/service/rest/v1/components?repository=myRepo&group=myGroup`;


// returns first 10 results
async function fetchData(url) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
  headers.append(
    "Authorization",
    "Basic <BASE64-STRING-HERE>"
  );
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  // Fetch request and parse as JSON
  const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
  let data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

// called at `/api/get-data`
export default async function getData(req, res) {
  try {
    let result = await fetchData(requestUrl);
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "failed to load data" });
  }
}
```

This returns an object containing an array of 10 records and the `continuation token`, a string, e.g.

```
{"items":[{"id": 1, "name": "itemOne"}, {"id": 2, "name": "itemTwo"}, etc.],"continuationToken":"07929bf0c78cf6c92d4acd0bf5823d80"}}
```

On the last page of records, the `continuationToken` is `null`:

```
{"items":[{"id": 99, "name": "itemNinetyNine"}, {"id": 100, "name": "itemOneHundred"}, etc.],"continuationToken": null}}
```

To get the complete set of records using recursion, this is the strategy I have tried, but haven't been successful:

```
async function recursivelyFetchData(url) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
  headers.append(
    "Authorization",
    "Basic <BASE-64-STRING>"
  );
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  try {
    // Fetch request and parse as JSON
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    let data = await response.json();
    // create a storage array
    let storage = [];
    // Set a variable for the next page url
    let nextPageUrl;
    // if the initial response contains a continuation token, start to recurse
    if (data.continuationToken) {
      // remove the query param so we don't keep adding it to the url string on each iteration
      let strippedUrl = url.replace(/&continuationToken=.*/g, "");
      // create the url with the query param
      nextPageUrl =
        strippedUrl + `&continuationToken=` + data.continuationToken;
      // store the next response
      let nextPageResponse = await recursivelyFetchData(
        nextPageUrl,
        requestOptions
      );
      // parse
      let nextPageData = await nextPageResponse.json();
      // add to storage
      storage = [...data, ...nextPageData.items];
    }
    // break recursion
    return storage;
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "failed to load data" });
  }
}

export default async function getData(req, res) {
  try {
    let result = await recursivelyFetchData(requestUrl);
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "failed to load data in getPackages" });
  }
}
```

I've tried the approaches found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337587/return-paginated-output-recursively-with-fetch-api), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041035/recursive-fetch-request), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409024/is-there-some-way-to-make-recursive-fetch-requests), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129245/javascript-using-fetch-and-pagination-recursive), and [here](https://dev.to/haalto/recursively-fetch-data-from-paginated-api-34ig), but this API is different from other paginated responses in that it relies on a continuation token in the response body, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to recursively add the query parameter to the url, continue iterating until the continuation token is `null`, then break recursion.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is a simple approach.  `fetchAllPages` fetches the first page, and then checks to see if the result has a non-nil `continuation` token.  If it doesn't we just returns the items from the result.  But if it does, we merge that token into a new url and recur, combining the current items with the newly-fetched ones into a single array.

Relying on a helper `addToken` function that builds our URL, it looks like this:

```js
const fetchAllPages = (url) => fetch (url)
  .then (res => res .json ())
  .then (
    ({items, continuationToken: token}) => token
      ? fetchAllPages (addToken (url, token)) .then (newItems => [...items, ...newItems])
      : items
  )
```

We alter it slightly to show where your header manipulation and such would fit, in a snippet that uses a dummy `fetch` function that returns `item0` - `item33` paginated in groups of ten and an implementation of `addToken` that does URL manipulation using DOM methods (rather than string parsing/hacking):

```js
const addToken = (base, token) => {
  const url = new URL (base)
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams (url .search)
  searchParams .set ('continuationToken', token)
  url .search = searchParams
  return url .toString ()
}

const fetchAllPages = (url) => {
  // configure fetch parameters (headers, etc.)
  return fetch (url, /*headers, whatever*/)
    .then (res => res .json ())
    .then (
      ({items, continuationToken: token}) => token 
        ? fetchAllPages (addToken (url, token)) .then (newItems => [...items, ...newItems])
        : items
    )
}

fetchAllPages ('https://baseURL.com/service/rest/v1/components?repository=myRepo&group=myGroup')
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// dummy version of `fetch` to demo without a real server
const fetch = (() => {
  const data = Array .from ({length: 34}, (_, id) => ({id, name: `item ${id}`}))
  const pageSize = 10
  return async (s) => {
    console .log (`fetching '${s}'`)
    const url = new URL (s)
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams (url .search)
    const start = searchParams .get ('continuationToken') || '0'
    const startIndex = data .findIndex (({id}) => id == start)
    const token = startIndex < 0 || (startIndex + pageSize >= data.length) ? null : data [startIndex + pageSize] .id
    return {json: () => ({
      items: data .slice (startIndex, startIndex + pageSize), 
      continuationToken: token ? String (token) : null
    })}
  }
})()
</script>
```